# Need to modify OS of a device which use Embeded linux with u-boot

Tags: linux, boot, embedded, bios, u-boot

I have a Congatec device running Linux with U-Boot (U-Boot SPL 2015.10+fslc+g4e28939_).
I need to modify certain settings within this embedded Linux environment.

The challenge lies in the fact that the device lacks SSH or Telnet connectivity options.
I attempted to boot a live Linux system on the device in order to perform a chroot, but it appears there is no BIOS or similar mechanism to boot from a USB flash drive.
I also tried various keyboard combinations to access the BIOS without success. The only open port I found is Port 80.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to access the Linux environment on this device?

Comment: You need to find out the cpu architecture, 32bit or 64. Arm, Mips, etc? Do you have a console, uart, or serial to connect to? Can you interupt the UBoot boot process, and issue commands to it? Can you link/upload a product sheet, or HiDef internal pictures into an edit of your question?

Comment: I tried to intrupt uboot boot process with keyboard without success. There are two ethernet port on device . there is no any technical dataseet